# hide a row and a div content after deletion using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, fadeout

> I want to fadeout a row and a div content after deletion in ajax,
>
> my view

```
              <table class="table table-hover text-center" id="myTable">
                            <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($get_all_mail as 
                              $get_all_mails) { ?>
                                    <tr onclick="return get_mail_content(<?
                 php echo $get_all_mails['m_id']; ?>)" id="target-list">     
                                <td class="email-title" >
                                    <?php echo $get_all_mails['from']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td class="email-body" >
                                    <?php echo $get_all_mails['subject'] ?>
                                </td>                                   
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo date('d-M-Y', 
                          strtotime($get_all_mails['start_date'])) ?>
                                </td>   
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>


                    <div class="content-box" id="content">

                    </div>
```

> my script

```
function get_mail_content(m_id) {
                        var datastring = 'm_id=' + m_id;
                        var a = false;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin/get_mail_contents",
                            data: datastring,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (result) {
                                alert(result);
                                var result = $.parseJSON(result);
                                console.log(result.from);
                                var d = new Date(result['0']['start_date'] + ' ' + result['0']['start_time']);
                                console.log(d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ',' + d.getDate() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getFullYear());
                                $('#content').html('');
                                $("#content").append('<div class="mail-toolbar clearfix" id="mail_content"> <a href="#" onclick = "return delete_mail(' + result['0']['m_id'] + ')"class="btn btn-danger mrg10L" title="Delete"> <i class="glyph-icon icon-trash-o"></i></a> </div></div> </div>');
                            }
                        });                           
                    }

                       function delete_mail(m_id) {
                        var datastring = 'm_id=' + m_id;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?> 
                          admin/delete_mails",
                            data: datastring,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (result) {
                                alert(result);                                                        
                $('#content').fadein(400).delay(2000).fadeout(2000);

                            }
                        });
                    }
```

> Here when i click on table row i fire a function (get_mail_content) for showing content in json format in a div whose id is container,with in this json format i fire an another function (delete_mail) for delete this content from table row and from div.[image]
>
> here in this image when i click on table row right side div will open ,i want when i click delete button i want to hide this div and table row(left side)from my page.

Comment: Hi, would something like this help? 
`$('#content').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#content').html(content);
    $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
});`

Comment: yes it working for content hide in right side,but how to hide this table row in left side of the above image

Comment: Hi, just do the same with the left side. do you have the id of left side. Let me post an answer. You mean to hide <td class="email-body" > as well?

Comment: yes working for both ,thank you very much.

Comment: sorry , it working but hide all rows from table here is my code$('#myTable').fadeOut('slow', function() { $('#myTable').html(content); $('#myTable').fadeIn('slow'); });

Comment: you're hiding the whole table here with `$('#myTable')` here, just select the inner id which you want to remove.

Comment: yes you are right ,it working ,thank you for your help

Comment: please accept my answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
$('#content').fadeOut('slow', function() 
  { 
       $('#content').html(content);
       $('#content').fadeIn('slow'); 

  });
```

Also do the same with all the ids which you need to hide and fadeout. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to associated id with the right side table

Example : 
id = "m_id_1",
Which is reference is to delete function , then you need to pass that id value in the delete arguments;

```
$('#content').fadeOut('slow', function() 
  { 
       $('#m_id_1').html(content);
       $('#m_id_1').fadeIn('slow'); 

  });
```